# Can't Authenticate Auth Token When Pushed to Heroku

Tags: ruby-on-rails, authentication, heroku

I have an app that works fine on my localhost. I've set the `session_store` as this.

```
Rails.application.config.session_store :cookie_store, key: '_myapp_session', domain: :all
```

When I push to heroku every POST I make displays `Can't verify CSRF token authenticity` error in my log. I have no idea why this isn't working. The parameters contain the authenticity token. For some reason the browser doesn't have the updated authenticity token. I'm running Rails 4.2. What could be wrong with this and how do I fix this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When using the domain: :all, it looks for a tld (top-level domain) length of 1. This is fine when the domain is "localhost" on your local machine but breaks in the real world.

I would recommend moving this code to an environment specific config file: config/environments/(development|production).rb

Here you can use your existing code for development, but set the actual domain for production.